# C#. Как обработать event динамически созданой кнопки(по нажатию на неё)

Tags: c#, button

Есть class House и class Room. В классе House, в поле Rooms[] хранится массив class Room. Эти кнопки отображают свободен/занят ли номер(создаются они динамически в завсимости от их кол-ва). Как сделать так чтобы по нажатию одной из кнопки, она отрабатывала событие. К примеру, нажимаю на кнопку 10, она меняет цвет на синий.

[image: Эти динамические кнопки]

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
var btn = new Button();
...
btn.Click += (sender, e) => { ... };
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! А => что за оператор?

Comment: @Ximik, лямбда-функция.

Comment: Я бы сказал, [лямбда-функция](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb397687.aspx) (лямбда-выражение).